# Why does a function in a contract, that creates a transaction, returns a transaction hash in return, even though I have written return bool?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Here is the sample code:

```
 function myFunc(string name) public returns(bool,bytes32)
{
    bytes32 hash= sha256(name);
    names[hash] = true; 
    return (true,hash);
}
```

Here names is mapping, I am trying to store names in blockchain. I have returned (true,hash), but when I call the function from frontend i receive the transaction hash. How can I get what i want to return?

Answer (score 4):

This is a "facts of life" thing.

You can `return(bool success`) and this will be visible to other contracts that call the function, e.g. in a chain of functions calling functions in other contracts.

Transactions always start with an externally owned account signing a transaction and submitting it to the network. The returned value is a transaction receipt. The outcome of the transaction is *unknown* because nothing has happened yet except that a *request* has been submitted to the network for verification *in the future*.

A typical approach to coping with this fact of life is to wait for the transaction to be mined, then inspect the transaction log for useful output, inspect the success/fail status and draw your own conclusions, or inspect a read-only function to discover the new state after the transaction was mined. The returned values are forever *out of reach* for a Web3 client.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So there is no way to implement what I want my contract to do, is that what you're saying? And it will always return transaction hash when i use web3?

Comment: if the function  changes state of the contract then you will get transaction hash. if it is not changing the state then you can return any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Hitches has explained it really well. But if you want return values, then you can use events. you can emit an event and add a listener in your app.